# Redshift - Finding number of times a particular values is store in a column in table

Tags: sql, casting, amazon-redshift

Given below is a view of my table that stores sale data along with the detail whether the customer is a new customer or not. I am trying to find if the same sale_id has multiple entries for the same customer and tags him as a new customer. Given below is a sample view of the table

```
cust_id,prod_id,sale_id,is_new_cust,store_type
1,prod_a,1001,t,store
2,prod_a,1002,,online
3,prod_a,1003,t,store
3,prod_a,1003,t,store
```

I need to find how many such customers exist that have the tag of is_new_cust for the same sale_id.

**Given below is the SQL I tried:**

```
select cust_id,count(is_new_cust) from sales 
where store_type = 'store' and is_new_cust='t'
group by cust_id having count(is_new_cust)> 1;
```

**Expected output:**

```
cust_id,count
3,2
```

The above SQL returns 1 no results.

I am using Amazon Redshift DB for the above.

Could anyone help me find where am I going wrong with the query. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select count(distinct cust_id) as num_customers,
       count(distinct case when is_new_cust = 't' then cust_id end) as num_new_customers
from sales 
where store_type = 'store';
```

However, this might be a simpler version that does what you want:

```
select count(*)
from sales
where store_type = 'store' and is_new_cust = 't';
```

This assumes the `is_new_cust` flag is set only once for a new customer.